# FO:Inline container shows nothing

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, apache-fop

Here is snippet of my xsl:

```
<fo:table-row height="27.8mm">
  <fo:table-cell border-bottom="0.2mm solid" number-columns-spanned="2">
    <fo:table border="0px solid"
              border-collapse="collapse"
              table-layout="fixed"
              width="100%"
              height="100%">
      <fo:table-column column-width="110mm"/>
      <fo:table-body>
        <fo:table-row height="27.8mm">
          <fo:table-cell border-bottom="0.2mm solid" height="28mm">
                <xsl:call-template name="LabelTemplate">
                  <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'REFERENCE'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:call-template name="ReferenceTemplate">
                  <xsl:with-param name="First" select="First"/>
                  <xsl:with-param name="Second" select="Second"/>
                  <xsl:with-param name="eNo" select="eNo"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
      </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
  </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

When using inline container inside `ReferenceTemplate` nothing is displayed.

```
<xsl:template name="ReferenceTemplate">
  <xsl:param name="First"/>
  <xsl:param name="Second"/>
  <xsl:param name="eNo"/>
  <xsl:param name="size" select="'22pt'"/>
  <xsl:param name="left" select="'5pt'"/>
  <xsl:param name="top" select="'15px'"/>
  <xsl:param name="text-indent" select="'5px'"/>
    <fo:block-container
            position="absolute"
            top="{$top}" left="{$left}" right="5pt"
            width="auto"
            border="0px solid"> 
     <fo:inline-container vertical-align="top" inline-progression-dimension="49.9%">
        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="$Second"/></fo:block>
     </fo:inline-container>
     <fo:inline-container vertical-align="top" inline-progression-dimension="49.9%">
        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="$First"/></fo:block>
     </fo:inline-container>
   </fo:block-container>
</xsl:template>
```

When using this sample instead of inline container content is displayed.

```
<fo:block text-align-last="justify">
  <xsl:value-of select="$Second"/>
  <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" />
  <xsl:value-of select="$First"/>
</fo:block>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot embed an `fo:inline-container` into an `fo:block-container`.

See [this reference for `fo:block-container`](https://www.data2type.de/xml-xslt-xslfo/xsl-fo/xslfo-referenz/elemente/fo-block-container/) - `fo:inline-container` is not in the list of allowed children.